# To fire file upload control on click event - xpage

Tags: xpages

Can anyone please advise how to fire file upload control in Xpage during OnClick or Onfocus event in IE? it works by default in Firefox.

Comment: You need to specify the IE version. IE does not do that. And what do you mean with "fire". You want to execute code when someone clicks where?

Comment: IE7- I want to execute file upload control ie, select files when on click or on focus of file uploade control.

Comment: AFAIK The file selection dialog isn't reachable via JavaScript. Otherwise it would be easy for malicious code to steal files via upload.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, when a person selects a file in the File Upload control, after it associates with the file, it is prepared for uploading (request phase data). The native control has a couple things to lack that I wish for in future releases, but basically to achieve "Upload" button functionality, which I recommend for reasons below, you should:

- Create a button control which triggers a Full Refresh (returning true if the SSJS getFilename() off the fileUpload control is true); note it must be a Full Refresh!
- Make sure you run it with "Process data without validation" checked (aka- disableValidators="true")

Your button should read like:

```
    <xp:button value="Upload" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete" disableValidators="true">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    getComponent("fileUpload1").getFilename()?true:false}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
```

All the users I've run into *expect* an "Upload" button. I'm not saying this is the best or most optimal way, but it is what people look for. My experience has taught me to cater to the users' expectations. They may be wrong to expect such, but it makes sense in the context of what we're doing here at least.

I'm sure there's a way of triggering a full refresh automatically, possibly with an onComplete event. I'm not sure whether this could be an onBlur event for the xp:fileUpload control or would be a different listener off the getComponent("fileUpload1").getFilename() value. Perhaps a more experienced XPage Dev. can answer that specifically.

Hope this helps.